# How to reconnect a websocket connection websocket-client

Tags: python, websocket

I've been trying to write code that collects crypto data from Binance. Binance auto disconnects after 24 hours. Is there any way for me to reconnect after disconnection? I believe running forever should take care of that for me, but it dies when an error is thrown. I will be running this program on a server 24/7. I will also need a way to be notified maybe telegram/discord bot that I can build where do I type the code to send when it is disconnected

This is the error I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exchanges/binance/binance_ticker.py", line 97, in <module>
    start()
  File "exchanges/binance/binance_ticker.py", line 94, in start
    rel.dispatch()
  File "/home/pyjobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rel/rel.py", line 205, in dispatch
    registrar.dispatch()
  File "/home/pyjobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rel/registrar.py", line 72, in dispatch
    if not self.loop():
  File "/home/pyjobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rel/registrar.py", line 81, in loop
    e = self.check_events()
  File "/home/pyjobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rel/registrar.py", line 232, in check_events
    self.callback('read', fd)
  File "/home/pyjobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rel/registrar.py", line 125, in callback
    self.events[etype][fd].callback()
  File "/home/pyjobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rel/listener.py", line 108, in callback
    if not self.cb(*self.args) and not self.persist and self.active:
  File "/home/pyjobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websocket/_app.py", line 349, in read
    op_code, frame = self.sock.recv_data_frame(True)
  File "/home/pyjobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 401, in recv_data_frame
    frame = self.recv_frame()
  File "/home/pyjobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 440, in recv_frame
    return self.frame_buffer.recv_frame()
  File "/home/pyjobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 352, in recv_frame
    payload = self.recv_strict(length)
  File "/home/pyjobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 373, in recv_strict
    bytes_ = self.recv(min(16384, shortage))
  File "/home/pyjobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 524, in _recv
    return recv(self.sock, bufsize)
  File "/home/pyjobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 122, in recv
    raise WebSocketConnectionClosedException(
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection to remote host was lost.
```

My code:

```py
import websocket
import rel


uri = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/!ticker@arr"


def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)


def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)
    write_logs(error)


def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("### closed ###")
    write_logs(str(close_status_code) + str(close_msg))
    start(


def on_open(ws):
    print("Opened connection")


start()
websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(uri,
on_open = on_open,
on_message=on_message,
on_error = on_error,
on_close (on_close)
ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel) #Set the dispatcher to automatic reconnection.
rel.signal(2, rel.abort) # Keyboard Interrupt
rel.dispatch()


    
start()
```

Comment: maybe you should run code in `try/except` to catch error and later run all again - so it will connect again

Comment: got it, Im trying this now. will add sleep after disconnection and run all again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The comment in this line of code `ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel) #Set the dispatcher to automatic reconnection.` could auto reconnection depending on rel module? And how the module rel and func dispatcher work together?

Comment: This answer would be more suitable as a comment

Answer (score 0):

as stated [here on github](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/issues/863#issuecomment-1261353428), the reconnect only properly works if you add a dispatcher and pass the reconnect parameters to run_forever which should not be zero (the default).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).